# i want to know can i write conditions in if() shorter than this?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
generate() {
  let divs = new Object();
  divs.div1 = base.randomdivs();
  divs.div2 = base.randomdivs();
  divs.div3 = base.randomdivs();
  divs.div4 = base.randomdivs();
  let randoms = new Object();
  randoms.randomLetter = base.random();
  randoms.letter = base.alphabet[randoms.randomLetter];
  randoms.letterIndex = base.alphabet.indexOf(randoms.letter);
  randoms.randomNumber = base.random();
  randoms.sum = randoms.letterIndex + randoms.randomNumber;
  randoms.answer1 = randoms.sum;
  randoms.answer2 = base.random();
  randoms.answer3 = base.random();
  randoms.answer4 = base.random();
  if (randoms.sum >= 26 || (randoms.answer1 == randoms.answer2 || randoms.answer1 == randoms.answer3 || randoms.answer1 == randoms.answer4) || (randoms.answer2 == randoms.answer1 || randoms.answer2 == randoms.answer3 || randoms.answer2 == randoms.answer4) || (randoms.answer3 == randoms.answer2 || randoms.answer3 == randoms.answer1 || randoms.answer3 == randoms.answer4) || (randoms.answer4 == randoms.answer2 || randoms.answer4 == randoms.answer3 || randoms.answer4 == randoms.answer1) || randoms.randomNumber == 0 || (divs.div1 == divs.div2 || divs.div1 == divs.div3 || divs.div1 == divs.div4) || (divs.div2 == divs.div1 || divs.div2 == divs.div3 || divs.div2 == divs.div4) || (divs.div3 == divs.div2 || divs.div3 == divs.div1 || divs.div3 == divs.div4) || (divs.div4 == divs.div2 || divs.div4 == divs.div3 || divs.div4 == divs.div1)) {
    return this.generate()
  } else {
    return [randoms, divs]
  }
}
}
```

i am trying to get differnt values in 2objects and cheking with if() i want to know can i write conditions in if() shorter than this?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code? What is this doing?

Comment: Show me the `randoms` and `divs`

Comment: It looks like you edited out the code that showed the generation of the `answer` and `div` elements, can you put it back? They're important.

Comment: This question is not answerable until you share your complete case and scenario and also the rest of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A way I found to slightly compress conditions like

`(randoms.answer1 == randoms.answer2 || randoms.answer1 == randoms.answer3 || randoms.answer1 == randoms.answer4)`

is to use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

For example, the mentioned snippet could be re-written as

`[randoms.answer2, randoms.answer3, randoms.answer4].includes(randoms.answer1)`

Furthermore, linebreaking would make it more readable.

Comment: This only checks whether the array contains *one* particular item - he's looking for *any* intersection.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're right and this should already constitute a significant simplification of the original conditional. On the other hand, I'm not sure if finding any intersection, is really what they are after (in which case your answer might hold a more general solution).

Answer (score 0):

Put the `answer` and `div` elements into an array instead of having numeric-indexed properties, to make the code more DRY. Then create a Set from the array, and check if the Set's size is 4:

```
 generate() {
   const divs = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     divs.push(base.randomdivs());
   }
   const randoms = {};
   // ...

   // ...
   random.answers = [randoms.sum];
   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     random.answers.push(base.random());
   }

   const divsSet = new Set(divs);
   const answersSet = new Set(random.answers);
   if (randoms.sum >= 26 || divsSet.size !== 4 || answersSet.size !== 4) {
     return this.generate()
   } else {
     return [randoms, divs]
   }
 }
```

Any time you're using numeric-indexed properties, like `prop1`, `prop2`, etc, that'a sure sign that you should use a different data structure, usually an array.

Comment: Much of the code above was in OP's original question, but he edited it out afterwards for some reason... if that's what the downvote was for